# How to check the value of a property of an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I need to find the number of times a property has a specific value in an object.

The object:

```
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};
```

I need to find the number of how many online have the value true

What I've tried so far:

```
function countOnline(obj) {
  let count = 0;
    for (let user in obj) {
      if (obj.user == true) {
      count++;
      }
    }
  return count;
}

console.log(countOnline(users)); // 0
console.log(users.Ryan.online); // true
```

```
console.log(countOnline(users)); // should return 2 as the number of online: true exists twice
```

Comment: You check for the wrong property. `if (obj.user == true) {` But you don't want to check for `user`, but for `online`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd `reduce` the `Object.values` of the object, incrementing the accumulator when `online` is true:

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

const onlineCount = Object.values(users).reduce((a, { online }) => a + online, 0);
console.log(onlineCount);
```

To fix your existing code, change the test to `obj[user].online === true` (or just `obj[user].online`):

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function countOnline(obj) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let user in obj) {
    if (obj[user].online === true) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Comment: Thank you, I also tried obj.user.online but it didn't work, didn't think to put it in brackets

Answer (score 1):

You need to access online property of `obj`

```
if (obj[user].online == true) or if (obj[user].online)
```

When you do `obj.user` it tries to find `user` property on `obj` whose value will be `undefined` as we don't have any property named `user` on `obj`

You can simply filter values based on online property and check length

```js
let users = {Alan: {age: 27,online: false},Jeff: {age: 32,online: true},Ryan: {age: 19,online: true}};


let count = Object.values(users)
                  .filter(({ online }) => online)
                  .length

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

let onlineUser  = Object.keys(users).filter(item => users[item].online).reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = users[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log("count:", Object.keys(onlineUser).length);
console.log("onlineUser:", onlineUser);
```